How to change background colour in Reactjs app without affecting other pages
I'm a beginner to Reactjs and while I was making a project I came across a problem. In my landing page I want it to have a background colour that is dark like thisA picture of a welcome screen with a dark background and a light square with some text on it
My only problem is that when I do this it affects the rest of my pages on the app, giving them a dark background. How do I fix this?
I tried to use modular css and give the body different class names but the background doesn't change. It stays as either black or white, it doesn't change depending on the page I'm on.

First, you have to understand the structure of your html page and apply the background colour to elements accordingly.
For example, if your index.html is:
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
  </body>

And your createRoot function is:
createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
)

Then everything in your app will be nested in root, which itself is nested in body. So instead of applying a background-color to body, you should apply a background colour to the top html element in your component. For example, in the code below the top element in my landing page is div with the class name of "landing-page":
function LandingPage(){
  return(
    <div className="landing-page">
      {/* Your landing Page content */}
    </div>
  )
}  

